# How do I get fine-grained undo in Vim

Tags: vim, undo

I find Vim's undo to be a bit too coarse. E.g. if I type something like this:

```
a // to go into edit mode
to be or not to ve
<esc> // to exit insert mode
```

Oops! I made a typo. I want to start undoing so I press `u`, but then it clears the whole line. **Is there a way to undo word-by-word or character-by-character?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So as you see from the others what you are asking for doesn't exist in Vi (AFAIK).

Undo undoes what your last action was. If your last action was to enter insert mode and then add a line and then exit insert mode. That will be undone, however if from the default mode you hit the "x" key then you will delete 1 character or if in visual mode with text selected the text will be deleted. If you hit undo then you will restore that one character or the text that was selected.

...You should think of this as an action, and actions can be atomically undone or restored

As mentioned previously if you wish to delete the previous word then you should be able to hit Ctrl + w and delete the previous word while remaining in insert mode.

If you exit insert mode you can navigate (motion) back a word with "b" forward a word with "w" to the end of a word with "e", and can cut (which leaves you in insert mode) with "c" or delete with "d". Both actions cut and delete can accept a motion following them so you can delete the current word / up to the next word with "dw" or cut the previous word with "cb"

This concept becomes more useful when you remember to use the "." command (in normal mode). This command is to repeat the last action. I have used this many times to find and replace a small group of words in a file (It is especially useful if you are paranoid about changing too much). The scenario would be the following:

File:

> This is my post
>
> really it is a test
>
> this is the middle
>
> This is the end

if I wanted to replace "is" with "was" I could write:
%s/\<is\>/was/g

however if I wanted to change the first line and the third line "is" to "was" (and I didn't know their line numbers, and I wanted to see if there were any other places I wanted to change is to was I could type
"/is"

hit "n" until I reach the place I want substituted, and then hit "cw" and type "was"
I can now hit "n" until I reach another place I want substituted and hit ".", and that will replace "is" with "was" (Note: my search string didn't limit to the word "is", just the two characters "is" so "This" & "this" will match in this case)

Comment: I like to think of the command `c` as _change_ instead of _cut_. This better explains why it switches to edit mode after removing the affected text...

Answer (score 30):

You can break undos via `:help i_ctrl-g_u`. You can map this if you want for every character, but that might a little bit complicated. Mapping this to space button is a way.

```
:inoremap <Space> <Space><C-g>u
```

After that every word can be undo via <kbd>u</kbd>

Comment: IMHO this answer should be accepted; though it probably isn't because it came to late to the show, what a pity. I mapped it to `Space`, `Return` and `Tab` and am pretty happy with that.

Comment: Also consider mapping it for CTRL-U which deletes up to the beginning of line.

Comment: Nifty!  I target this trick at big delete operations: `:inoremap <C-W> <C-G>u<C-W>`, `:inoremap <C-U> <C-G>u<C-U>`.

Comment: This works like a charm, every space hit adds it as a action to undo redo tree. It really saves a lot of time. Thanks for your help. 
:inoremap <Space> <Space><C-g>u works like divine

Comment: I really wish Vim had more sane defaults like this. You keep adding stuff just to make it work like a decent editor, and then you have to keep track of all those changes as well across systems.

Comment: Neat! save a lot of time. Thankyou .

Answer (score 11):

No, it is not possible and is actually not necessary either. Vim has a million ways of dealing with that. Try <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> for example. Or <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>. Or <kbd>b</kbd><kbd>r</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>. Or <kbd>T</kbd><kbd>space</kbd> to jump back instead of <kbd>b</kbd>. Or <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>w</kbd>.

You can, of course use most of these solutions in insert mode (by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> first), or bind one to your favorite key combination (`:help map` and `:help imap`).

Comment: Not really a solution so much as telling me my question is wrong.

Comment: I rather see this as a solution to your problem that you want to remove the last word you entered. If your question is about doing that using undo and undo only, your answer would be: no, not possible, which is a not helpful at all imo.

Comment: Ok, it does make sense that I should try to use the movement commands instead of a blunt undo.

Comment: As Terence Honles says, Vim's undo command is designed to undo the last action. If you can learn to anticipate this, then the undo feature can really work for you when composing and decomposing text. See my screencast: [Modal editing: undo, redo and repeat](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/modal-editing-undo-redo-and-repeat/) for a demonstration.

Comment: Undo is also a way to get back to previously entered text. Your million solutions do not cater to that at all.

Answer (score 9):

On Linux, using <kbd>control-w</kbd> while in input mode deletes the last 'word'.

Comment: Works great on OSX. Question: How to redo?

Comment: If you want to undo this as the above 2 comments mention then exit insert mode and use u to undo.