# undoing only one character in vim

Tags: vim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get fine-grained undo in Vim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895551/how-do-i-get-fine-grained-undo-in-vim)

Is there any way to do this? I use cream and I would like to simply undo each character when I press ctrl+z. It's very annoying when I don't realise and delete entire rows of writing.

Thanks, nikita.utiu!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895551/how-do-i-get-fine-grained-undo-in-vim
(Possible Duplicate)

Comment: See my answer in [How do I get fine-grained undo in Vim
](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895551/how-do-i-get-fine-grained-undo-in-vim/4360415#4360415).